# how i can determine that code or elements are blocked by not-IE browsers?

Tags: javascript, html

i have self-hosted ASP.NET web service and small HTML5 application that communicates with that service

when i try open this page in IE, browser show me notification that it has blocked ActiveX components and scripts. allowing browser to execute dynamic components, HTML/JS code working fine - queries reaches web-service, it generate needed data, send data that page needs
but when i open page in another browsers (Chrome, FF, etc), page does not reacts to the any data that server sends as callback. queries reaches web-service but all communication with page and host is stopping

all JS-libraries that i connect to page: 'jquery-2.1.0.min' and my own 'common.js'

so, how i can determine, what element is not working correctly in not-IE?

Comment: Start by opening the console and check for errors, you probably used ActiveX somewhere to some cross domain stuff, and it's only supported in IE.

Comment: Actually, in all likelihood, IE is not "working correctly" and your code relies on that incorrect behaviour to do what you want. jQuery 2 does not support IE 6, 7 or 8, so if you are using IE, you should use jQuery 1.11.1 instead. If you do that, you will probably find that your site is consistent across all browsers and it doesn't "work" on any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you can try to avoid these kinds of issues:

1. Use jQuery 1.11.1 instead of jQuery 2.1.0 to improve compatibility between browsers.
2. In Chrome, right click anywhere on the page and select Inspect element. You should see a debug window open at the bottom half of the page. Navigate to the Console tab in this window to see any JavaScript errors.
3. In Firefox, install the Firebug add-in and use that to debug.
4. Make sure that you are not using any ActiveX. That is only compatible with IE.
5. You can use sites such as [browsershots.org](https://browsershots.org/) to test browser compatibility
6. Don't use browser / platform specific technologies such as Flash, Silverlight etc.